# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputDate requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net5

I'm developing an `ASP.NET 5.0` `blazor web assembly` app. I need to have a datepicker in Dashboard Screen to select a date to display details.

Here is my code:

```
<input class="input" type="month" id="staffPicker" name="staffPicker"
        aria-label="Staff Sales Detail Period"
        @bind="StaffSaleDetailsPeriod"
        max="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM")">
```

I need to trigger an API call on change of date. So I tried to add `@onchange` to the above code as shown below.

```
<input class="input" type="month" id="staffPicker" name="staffPicker"
        aria-label="Staff Sales Detail Period"
        @bind="StaffSaleDetailsPeriod"
        max="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM")"
        @onchange="OnStaffSalePeriodChange">
```

But this gives new error as shown below:

> The attribute 'onchange' is used two or more times for this element.
> Attributes must be unique (case-insensitive). The attribute 'onchange'
> is used by the '@bind' directive attribute.

So I tried to replace the above `input` element with `<InputDate>` as shown below,

```
<InputDate class="input is-small"
        ValueExpression="() => StaffSaleDetailsPeriod"
        Value="StaffSaleDetailsPeriod"
        ValueChanged="(DateTime staffSalesPeriod) => OnStaffSalePeriodChange()"
        max="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM")"/>
```

This gives a runtime error as shown below:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputDate`1[System.DateTime] requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext. For example, you can use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputDate`1[[System.DateTime, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] inside an EditForm

What is missing or this `<InputDate>` cannot be used with EditForm? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input class="input" type="month" id="staffPicker" name="staffPicker"
        aria-label="Staff Sales Detail Period"
        @bind="StaffSaleDetailsPeriod"
        max="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM")"
        @onchange="OnStaffSalePeriodChange">
```

When you use the @bind compiler directive, the compiler creates , behind the scenes, some code, the result of which is as if you've done something like this:

```
<input class="input" type="month" id="staffPicker" name="staffPicker"
            aria-label="Staff Sales Detail Period"
            value="StaffSaleDetailsPeriod"
            max="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM")"
            @onchange="@((args) => OnStaffSalePeriodChange=args.Value.ToString())">
```

Thus if you use @bind, you can't use the @onchange directive, but you can do what I did above.

As for the second issue: The InputDate component must be embedded within an EditForm whose Model attribute **or** EditContext are having the necessary value